# Check whether a line is present in a class using Mockito

Tags: android, junit, mockito, powermockito

I am currently studying about Junit test cases, Mockito, Power Mockito and reflection. I am stuck somewhere in between, I want to check in a class whether a statement exits in that class or not using mockito. I have no idea that can I do that or not. I want to search "AndroidSupportInjection.inject(this)" line in that class. If anybody has idea how to do that. Please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are trying to search for that line in order to override the Dagger 2 request for injection and inject your own test doubles.

This is probably the wrong way to do things.

The best way to perform automated UI tests against Activities and Fragments is to isolate the depenedencies you want inside Dagger 2 modules and then use build variants to swap these with test doubles.

There is an example of this in the [Google Android Architecture Blueprints](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/tree/todo-mvp-dagger/)

If this doesn't work, you could try using a setter on the injector like in [DaggerMock](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=daggermock&atb=v41-4&ia=software)

Comment: Totally agree with the above answer, though I would wanna use Test Components to switch modules on a TestApp to be used with Espresso. But if this is about a lint check to catch silly errors you can consider http://tools.android.com/tips/lint-custom-rules Because we're using dagger-android's dispatching injector factories, in case of a miss in invoking injection the compile time validation doesn't provide fruitful result